# Having trouble building c++ project in Eclipse CDT in OS X for a silly reason

Tags: c++, g++, eclipse-cdt, builder

I'm trying to build a very simple c++ program in eclipse and I'm getting a very silly error:

---

```
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -oMyFirst.o ../MyFirst.cpp
g++ -oLinkedLists MyFirst.o
ld: unknown option: -oLinkedLists
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

Time consumed: 403  ms.

---

The problem is that g++ in osx does not like the -o flag in the "g++ -oLinkedLists MyFirst.o" command right next to the executable file name... Does anybody know how to either configure g++ to accept that or how to configure the builder in eclipse such that there's a space between the -o flag and and file name like this:  "g++ -o LinkedLists MyFirst.o"?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark actually pointed me in the right direction but what I had to do to make it work was to go to:
Project >> Properties >> C/C++ Build >> Tool Chain Editor

I then changed the "Current toolchanin" select box to "MacOSX gcc" and that fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

To further clarify this issue, the solution isn't necessarily to use the MacOSX gcc toolchain. The problem is with the command line pattern for the linker in the toolchain. All you need to do to fix the problem is to edit the command line pattern to ensure there are spaces between each term.

By default, the command line pattern for the Linux gcc linker is something like:
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG}${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT}${INPUTS}

Note the lack of spaces between ${OUTPUT_PREFIX} and ${OUTPUT}. This is the crux of the problem. Simply add a space between those two terms, and your problem is solved.

Comment: Firstly - thanks, agodbehere! I looked a lot of places before finding this! To Answer hdx, on the version of Eclipse I am using (Eclipse platform 3.5.2) the command line pattern is at: project->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings and choose the first 'tab' Tool Settings, click on GCC C++ Compiler line and in the right side of the pane you should see 'Expert Settings: Command line pattern'. Make sure to change it for all your configurations (e.g debug and release) and repeat for the GCC C++ Linker also (i.e. click on it on the left also and then insert the space in the command line on the right).

Comment: One other thing - this has apparently now been fixed so should be ok in future versions hopefully: Bugzilla – Bug 232373

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse CDT 3.5 on OSX 10.5 and it works -

```
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -I/opt/local/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc/tet.o ../src/tet.cpp
g++ -o tet src/tet.o
Build complete for project tet
```

I get a space in the link line for my executable tet

I am using the default settings

In settings->C/C++ Build->Settings->Mac OSX C++ linker the comand line pattern is

${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}